# nodejs connects to localmachine instead of MYSQL server

Tags: mysql, node.js

I cannot connect to mysql using nodejs

```
var DatabaseConnection = function (databaseParam) {

//var driver = databaseParam.database_driver;

this.connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "192.168.11.178",
    database: "ecommerce",
    user: "ecommerce",
    password: "adhgfhjgfh"
});
this.connection.connect(function (err) {
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    console.log('you are now connected to '+hostname);
});
```

> ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'ecommerce'@'192.168.11.16' (using password: YES)

But `192.168.11.16` is my local-machine IPaddress when iam trying to connect to the `192.168.11.178`. I can easily connect using PHP but not using nodejs.

Also i tried with `mysql -u ecommerce -p -h 192.168.11.178` was successful. Also under privileges i have wildcard (%)

Iam using **mysql: 2.12.0**

Comment: You've misread the error message: that IP is supposed to be yours, not the server's. So it's all fine.

Comment: but i can easily connect with php on the my localmachine with the same user also i am able to connect using terminal

Comment: That doesn't change what the IP address in the error means. Seriously.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server-side technology so would be run *on the server*. You've obviously bound your mysql instance to `192.168.11.178` proven by your successful terminal connection. Perhaps you also ran this on the database server itself? If that's the case maybe you need to update your user privileges to allow `ecommerce'@'192.168.11.16`, using your example:

```
grant select on ecommerce.* to 'ecommerce'@'192.168.11.16' identified by 'adhgfhjgfh';
```

Modify to allow the privileges you want.